# Android: Record Screen Activity

Tags: android, video-capture

I am planning to record the screen activity of the user for a demo of three Android Applications that I created.

I think I've done good research on Google and the Play Store and so far, the solutions I saw either needed an application that was not free, using the Google USB Driver (which is not compatible with the OSX), or an application that required root.

I need an application (either installed in the Android Device or the Mac OSX) that can record the screen activity of the Android Device that is free, does not require root, and does not require any intermediate hardware in order to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Android 4.4, there is a screen recording feature accessible via adb.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord

> The screenrecord command is a shell utility for recording the display of devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher. The utility records screen activity to an MPEG-4 file, which you can then download and use as part of a video presentation. This utility is useful for developers who want to create promotional or training videos without using a separate recording device.